# Cronet and ExperimentalCronetEngine

Tags: chromium, cronet

Are there any drawbacks to use ExperimentalCronetEngine instead of CronetEngine? We would like to experiment with the network quality estimator, which is only exposed in ExperimentalCronetEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Every CronetEngine is really an ExperimentalCronetEngine, you can cast between them.  APIs on CronetEngine will be supported forever, while ExperimentalCronetEngine APIs may come and go.